# ASP.NET MVC and Subdomains Urls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I have a Virtual App at ~/blog using this subdomain blog.fujiy.net

To get the correct links I am using this configuration:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But, if anyone access blog.fujiy.net/blog it doesn´t redirect to blog.fujiy.net.

I can´t fix this. I tried so many configs....
Every time that I try to do a condition if url starts with /blog/ IIS always returns true, then I get a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Regex scares me, but try this; it seems to work on a quick test:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Remove Virtual Directory" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog\..*" />
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/blog" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only out-of-box supported scenario is this:

You have two or more applications: call them server.example.com/foo and server.example.com/bar.  You can configure IIS’s rewriting to do a simple subdomain -> application path mapping, e.g. foo.example.com -> server.example.com/foo; foo.example.com/path -> server.example.com/foo/path; bar.example.com/path -> server.example.com/bar/path, etc.  In these examples, the subdomain itself must map directly to the application root.

To work through this, foo.example.com/customers/view/42 will map to server.example.com/foo/customers/view/42, which if you’re using the standard {controller}/{action}/{id} route tokenizes to { controller = customers, action = view, id = 42 }.